# How to load S3 data into local memory, rather than saving to a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

This is my current code:

```
import (
  "time"
  "reflect"
  "io/ioutil"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
)

f, err := os.Create(filename)
if err != nil {
  panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to create file %q, %v", filename, err))
}
_, err = db.Downloader.Download(f, &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucketName"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKeyThatMightExist"),
})
if err != nil { // key doesn't exist
  os.Remove(filename)
  return nil
} else {
  file, err = ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
}
```

I need `file` to be a string that is what was pulled down from S3. The local file that I am storing is a cache for what is on S3.

This means that when I try to pull down data, I need to create a file for that data. Due to the database I'm working with, I don't  actually know if the key I'm accessing even exists. I was wondering if either of these solutions would be possible: 1) Create some type of buffer object, to load the whole file into RAM, without actually saving it. 2) Check if the file exists on S3, without creating a local file. This would let me then pull down the file if it existed, while not creating an empty file if I didnt exist on S3.

Sorry, but I can't create a playground link, as go playground does not have the libraries I need for this example.

Comment: please provide full reproducible example.

Comment: List the object items in the bucket to see if the image file exists or not.

Comment: If im correct about the package you are using (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Downloader.DownloadWithContext) then please check https://godoc.org/github.com/dsnet/golib/memfile

Comment: I edited it with more code. That better?

Comment: Also, in response to mh-cbon, I don't know the length of the file. Thanks, but I can't create a byte array, as the data I'm pulling is a encoded protobuf. I can't get the length of the data, as I need the data forst to find the length.

Comment: no a reproducible code would be compilable and runnable. Maybe via play.golang.org (although it has limitations). Here, for example, you are not showing the imported package, so it s pure guess.

Comment: I added the imports. All of the code I have is in a function, where you are given both a filename and a key name, and the function returns the decoded protobuf from S3 or a local cache. Sorry I don't know how to ask a question with every one of the 1 million requirements

Comment: if you don t know the object size ahead of time, then the code is not reliable, assuming you have a smart io.WriterAt, you might consume the whole memory. Writing to a file is safer anyway.

Comment: @NeilMacneale Create a buffer of length of the image after converting the image into base64 and then use that buffer to flush the data coming from the bucket.

Comment: Its not an image. I think what @mh-cbon said before, that I should just save it to a file, is my answer. Also, I'm creating the data on another server, so I don't even have the data before its encoded and put on S3.

Comment: @NeilMacneale what you are doing there is nothing wrong with that if it is a file it will be downloaded from S3 if it exists if not then it will throw an error. So what is actually you are asking.

Comment: one simple solution is to use a temporary file then apply a rename of the file, or remove. https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile. Another would involve a struct that embeds an os.File then checks for the first `WriteAt` to actually create the file on the FS. I suspect you ll have to guard the write operations with a mutex.

Comment: Can you write that as an answer? thats a great solution. Thanks

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/4z8rcWEZ8Os

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
downloader.Download(buf, &requestInput)
```

Now you can use `buf.Bytes()`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#NewWriteAtBuffer